# client <--> Raspberry Pi <---> Router (LAN )

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless, server

How is it possible to redirect all the traffic from the client to the raspberry pi (in order to analyse it and block some packets. it's like a firewall) and then send to to the router and vice-versa !

for the two cases: wireless and wire

Besides we don't have access to the router to make change or configuration.

raspberry pi is like a man in the middle but the client knows that

Comment: Finally after a long research I found that I have to turn My Raspberry Pi into a router ! Sorry guys, but I have to thank **Google** for his help ! :P

Comment: Ok, and how did you do that? Add an answer to your own question, please, so that we all know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to do that.

If you want to analyze your traffic, you need to use a tool like Wireshark or TShark to sniff the packets as they go by. It works by setting your pi to [Promiscuous Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) so the you see all the traffic, not just the traffic for that address.

Comment: ok after using  wireshark what can you do ... nothing of course because wireshark can only visualize the packets  but not controlling them ! if you see what I mean ...